# ASP.NET website http requests appear to be queueing

Tags: iis-6, asp.net

We cloned our servers this weekend into a colo.  All non-asp.net sites are performing great, but ASP.NET sites are very slow.  It appears to be an issue with the requests/connections, but I cannot figure out where.

The reason I think it is a problem with the connections is that when I launch fiddler and watch the requests, all requests appear to happen sequentially.  Even the static image requests are taking 5 seconds and another one doesn't start until the first one finishes.

MaxConnections is set to 100 in machine.config and the "website connections" are set to unlimited.

Any idea what else coudld be causing this?

from machine.config:

Comment: Some more info.  Running Trace shows that pages are executing quickly, in 1/10 of a second or less.  Running Profiler on DB shows that the queries are running quickly.  I'm thinking this has to be a connection issue of some kind.

Comment: Using MS Round Trip Visualizer, it appears that TTFB is always 5000ms.   If that 5 seconds were gone on all requests I think the site would run fine.  Is there a delay setting somewhere that potentially got changed?

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by our internal 301 redirect tool, so nothing that anyone could have helped me with! :)